# TYPO3 6.2 -> PHP 5.3 -> MySQL issue

Tags: php, mysql, exception, content-management-system, typo3

I am stuck at a problem about setup a old **TYPO3 6.2** project. I am forced to use PHP 5.3 and I am not able to use MySQLi, TYPO3 throws an error:

> 1271492607:Database Error: PHP mysqli extension not loaded. This is a must have for TYPO3 CMS!

How can I enable **MySQLi** now?

Using Ubuntu 16.04, downloaded **PHP 5.3** and the **MySQL extension** from ppa, [here](https://launchpad.net/~sergey-dryabzhinsky/+archive/ubuntu/php53)

I am thankful for any help

Comment: Do you have another version of php installed too? Did you restart the webserver?

Answer (score 0):

Is the `php53-mod-mysql` installed and also activated? Create an `test.php` with the content `<?php php_info(): ?>` to check if the mysqli module is loaded. Otherwise you should check your php.ini, or the `/etc/php5/conf.d` respective the `/etc/php5/mods-available/` directory if the module is available.

You can also try to run the command `php5enmod mysqli` and after that restart your Apache (`service apache2 restart`) and try again.

Comment: Thanks for you response Rene. That is a problem. i didn't have a **mods-available** in my `etc/php53/.` folder. And also seems like the mod is not enabled. i cant find something in my php.ini about that mod, even if its installed.

Comment: then try to run `apt-get install php53-mod-mysql`