# PHP 5.3 issue with Mysqli

Tags: php, mysqli, typo3

I am trying to setup a **TYPO3 6.2** project and i am forced to use **PHP 5.3** to get this run.

**Using:**

- Ubuntu 16.04 LTE.
- Apache2

**Problem:**

- i downloaded **PHP 5.3** from **SergeyD PPA**
- TYPO3 gives me this Error:

  > #1271492607: Database Error: PHP mysqli extension not loaded. This is a must have for TYPO3 CMS!
- I downloaded `php53-mod-mysql` from **SergeyD PPA** it says that includes mysqli as well.
- I dont have any **php.ini** inside my downloaded`/etc/php53/apache2`. I thought a solution could be to download the **php.ini** from official **php.net** for the same version, so I did than. cp the **php.ini** inside my `/etc/php53/apache2` to enable mysqli But seems like that didn't worked.

I am checking that with a `phpinfo();`
This is the output:[PHP Output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XeTpH.png)

**Question:**

- How can I enable **MySQLi** in this scenario.
- Other ways to reach goal? Some Workarounds? (I am new in the WebDev. scene atm)

Comment: php.ini lives in /etc root dir - as in /etc/php.ini

Comment: Did you find the path of php.ini with phpinfo() ?

Comment: if you do phpinfo and then look at the output, and search for `php.ini` it will tell you exactly where the used configuration resides

Comment: you should consider upgrading your php version as php 5.3 is no longer supported.

Comment: @NitishKumarDiwakar as is TYPO3 6.2 since April of this year

Comment: i added my phpinfo() output. please have a look guys.
and i checked my existing **php.ini** with **locate php.ini** and there was no.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [TYPO3 6.2 -> PHP 5.3 -> MySQL issue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45352100/typo3-6-2-php-5-3-mysql-issue)

Comment: Sometimes you should not put things together which are not fitting.

Answer (score 1):

I solved a similar problem with the intl extension for php.

[How to install PHP intl extension in Ubuntu 14.04](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42243461/how-to-install-php-intl-extension-in-ubuntu-14-04/42243651#42243651)

The Ubunto version doesn't matter in this scenario. You should try the solution with the mysqli extension.

Im not sure, btu you could try:

```
sudo apt-get install php5-mysqli
```